# Vertical Align Wrapper

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I'm messing around with a website out of boredom, and trying to figure out how to vertical align my wrap, which I am failing at lol. I've already horizontally aligned it, and just need help vertical aligning it. (Yes, I have tried vertical-align:middle, but it doesn't work).

```
    * { margin:0;  padding:0; }
    html { height:100%; }
    body { background:/*url(images/bg.jpg)*/#14181a; }
    #wrap { width:960px;  height:55%;  margin:0 auto;  background:#293033; }

    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="navgation"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to support older browsers, you can use a display box. I have the following class:

```
.vertically_centered {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;

  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;

  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  box-pack: center;
  box-align: center;
}
```

Then put just about anything inside there. Since you want the "wrap" div vertically centered, try assigning the vertically_centered class to your body element.

For more detailed information on using the flexible box, you might want to check out this article: [http://www.css3.info/introducing-the-flexible-box-layout-module/](http://www.css3.info/introducing-the-flexible-box-layout-module)

Answer (score 1):

Vertical aligns can be accomplished using table layouts. You need an element displaying as a table-cell and it's parent should display as a table. Then you can add vertical alignment and it'll work.

First, here's a js fiddle showing it in action. It centers the contents of the wrap inside the wrap! (if I misunderstood and you need to center the wrap itself, just ask and I'll edit) http://jsfiddle.net/YWdDC/1/

```
    * { margin:0;  padding:0; }
    html { height:100%; }
    .wrap-wrapper {
        background: url('images/bg.jpg') #14181a;
        display: table;
     }
    .wrap {
        width:960px;
        height:300px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:#293033;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }​

    <div class="wrap-wrapper">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="logo">Logo</div>
            <div id="navgation">Nav</div>
            <div id="content">Content</div>
            <div id="footer">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>​
```

Comment: Cross-browser? But IE7 doesn't support table, table-row, and table-cell, evidently: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to vertical-align a div object, use position:relative and a top value, like so:

```
#wrap {width:960px; height:55%; margin:0 auto; background:#293033; position:relative; top:20px;}
```

If you want to align text inside the #wrap div with a specific vertical alignment, such as dynamic superscript, use vertical-align on the text container:

```
#wrap span {font-size:14px; line-height:16px; vertical-align:2px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is the exact issue discussed in [this post](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

> Method 1
>
> The following example makes two (non-trivial) assumptions. If you can
>   meet these assumptions, then this method is for you:
>
> 1. You can put the content that you want to center inside a block and specify a fixed height for that inner content block.
> 2. It's alright to absolutely-position this content. (Usually fine, since the parent element inside which the content is centered can still be in flow.
>
> If you can accept the above necessities, the solution is:
>
> 1. Specify the parent container as position:relative or position:absolute.
> 2. Specify a fixed height on the child container.
> 3. Set position:absolute and top:50% on the child container to move the top down to the middle of the parent.
> 4. Set margin-top:-yy where yy is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.
>
> ...
>
> Method 2
>
> This method requires that you be able to satisfy the following
>   conditions:
>
> 1. You have only a single line of text that you want to center.
> 2. You can specify a fixed-height for the parent element.
>
> If you can accept the above necessities, the solution is:
>
> 1. Set the line-height of the parent element to the fixed height you want.

I find Method 2 generally is the simplest and most consistent way to vertical align, although it is limited to a single line, which is usually fine because most of my vertical aligning needs are for menu items which only need a single line anyway.